# PHP question: how to combine syntax?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, comparison

could someone please tell me where the mistake is in my PHP code? My PHP knowledge is extremely rudimentary although I have tried it with http://php.net/manual/de/language.operators.logical.php :-D

"translated" it should mean something like:

- Single Post -> Show reading time: yes
- Custom Post Type "wpdmpro" -> Show reading time: no

The function for the reading time works per se, but not in the way I put it together concerning the combination with the CPT.

With my code the reading time is not shown - neither in the CPT nor in the normal single post:

```
//  Reading Time

if (function_exists('readingtime') )  if ( is_single() && !  'wpdmpro' == get_post_type() )  

{      
echo '<span class="text-sep text-sep-cat">/</span>';               
echo readingtime();
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is incorrect:

```
if ( is_single() && !  'wpdmpro' == get_post_type() )
```

That essentially means:

```
if ( is_single() && false == get_post_type() ) {
```

Which will never be true. To check if a value does not equal another value, use `!==`:

```
if ( is_single() && 'wpdmpro' !== get_post_type() )
```

Also, the way you've combined the two `if` statements is hard to read and prone to errors. Instead, just add the first statement as a condition to the one statement:

```
if ( function_exists('readingtime') && is_single() && 'wpdmpro' !== get_post_type() ) {      
    echo '<span class="text-sep text-sep-cat">/</span>';               
    echo readingtime();
}
```

Comment: thank you, but now it shows the function "readingtime" not only on normal single posts but also at the custom post type "wpdmpro" - but it should only show at normal single posts, and NOT at CPT "wpdmpro"

Comment: Is `wpdmpro` definitely the correct name of the post type? Are you using this code inside [the loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/)? Did you use my code exactly?

Comment: yes, the cpt is right and it is inside the loop; all other functions for my normal single posts work fine in that file (ENFOLD theme loop-index.php) - except for that, it won't exclude at the CPT wpdmpro.
It's the CPT from https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/

Comment: The `loop-index.php` filename implies that the file is used as a template for an archive or other list view, but you're using `is_single()`, which doesn't make any sense. Are you sure you're looking at the right file for what you're looking at on the front-end?

Comment: yes, it is the right file - I put some other function snippets in it. But now it works - I have no idea why. Thanks a lot for your time!